# Android Emulator: Apps has stopped working & keep stops working

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-emulator

This is my logcat. My xml and java has no error and I don't know why this error is happening.

```
09-11 13:59:00.227 1358-4700/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
09-11 13:59:00.227 1358-4700/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
09-11 13:59:00.227 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
09-11 13:59:00.237 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
09-11 13:59:00.237 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 13:59:00.296 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
09-11 13:59:05.482 1358-2355/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
09-11 13:59:05.483 1358-2355/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
09-11 13:59:05.493 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
09-11 13:59:05.515 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
09-11 13:59:05.515 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 13:59:05.517 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
09-11 13:59:10.626 1358-3721/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
09-11 13:59:10.626 1358-3721/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
09-11 13:59:10.626 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
09-11 13:59:10.641 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
09-11 13:59:10.641 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 13:59:10.672 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
09-11 13:59:15.155 8980-8980/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-11 13:59:15.155 8980-8980/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-11 13:59:15.195 8983-8983/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-11 13:59:15.196 8983-8983/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-11 13:59:15.767 1358-1401/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
09-11 13:59:15.767 1358-1401/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
09-11 13:59:15.767 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
09-11 13:59:15.784 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
09-11 13:59:15.784 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 13:59:15.791 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
09-11 13:59:17.974 9008-9008/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-11 13:59:17.974 9008-9008/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-11 13:59:19.005 9017-9017/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2, PID: 9017
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2/com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
09-11 13:59:21.202 1358-3721/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
09-11 13:59:21.202 1358-3721/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
09-11 13:59:21.202 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
09-11 13:59:21.380 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
09-11 13:59:21.380 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 13:59:21.530 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
09-11 13:59:26.651 1358-1358/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
09-11 13:59:26.651 1358-1358/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
09-11 13:59:26.652 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
09-11 13:59:26.658 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
09-11 13:59:26.661 1250-1289/? E/vold: Failed to open /proc/7488: No such file or directory
09-11 13:59:26.663 1756-2081/system_process E/MountService: Failed to unmount appfuse.
09-11 13:59:26.664 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 13:59:26.687 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
09-11 13:59:31.792 1358-4700/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
09-11 13:59:31.792 1358-4700/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
09-11 13:59:31.792 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
09-11 13:59:31.802 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
09-11 13:59:31.802 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
09-11 13:59:31.804 3487-8295/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
```

Comment: "Not enough memory"

Comment: What's happening in `MainActivity::onCreate()`? You're getting a `NullPointerException` on line 48.

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at com.example.xh3al3r.myapplication2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)*

Comment: The log says 'setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference'. So you are trying to set onCliclListener on NULL object and this happened in 'MainActivity' on line 48

Comment: How much RAMs you'd specified? Must be 4Gb and above these days.

Comment: Probably a `findViewById()` call has returned `null`.

Comment: @MichaelDodd OK! got it, the id declare in java file and xml file had typo mistake. BUT my emulator wont display my layout...

Comment: @InfiniteLoops 2048gb

Comment: @JesscyTey In which case you're welcome to ask a new question explaining your new issue, but I would strongly advise reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) beforehand.

Comment: Noted. xD Btw i still having the same error after i modify the id name.
the code below start from line 48
rellay_salarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainAlarm.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: @JesscyTey like i said, 4Gb and above.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to initialize the button in the `oncreate()` method before set onClickListener

```
yourButtonName=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
```

Than try to set click listener on it . 
Hope So its help you :)

Comment: i did declare at my java file, but still error

Comment: not just declare also initialize it like i did that